Выбрасывается ошибка из-за того, что поле сущности, помеченное аннотацией @Formula, не содержится в полученном ResultSet
Имеется сущность, содержащая как обычные, так и вычисляемые поля через аннотацию @Formula.
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@AuditTable(value = "persons_AUD", schema = "history")
@Audited
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Formula("CONCAT_WS( ' ', surname, name, middle_name ) ")
    @NotAudited
    private String fullName;
}

После миграции со Spring Boot 2 на Spring Boot 3 при выполнении кастомного запроса начала выбрасыватсья следующая ошибка:

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
Unable to find column position by name: fullName [Колонки fullName не
найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

При этом методы вроде findAll() такой ошибки не вызывают.
До перехода на версию Spring Boot 3 такой ошибки не происходило.
Сам запрос имеет следующий вид:
@Query(value = " SELECT distinct p.* FROM persons p", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findBySomeCustomRequest();

Также прилагаю скриншот, показывающий, что метод работал на версии Spring Boot 2


Точно этот запрос раньше работал? Он не должен был. Ему негде fullName взять.

Проверил ещё раз на Spring Boot 2 версии программы и приложил скриншот к вопросу, все работает

Загадка. А какой SQL выполняется в старой версии? Не ясно откуда он значения берет в нативном запросе.
